# How do I add libraries to pymol?

Tags: python, anaconda, pymol

I have pymol downloaded and in use on my mac. I open it from the applications folder. I can successfully run a python script in it. However, I cannot import any libraries within that script. The way I currently know to add importable libraries to a python environment is through anaconda navigator. Is there a way to get anaconda to see the pymol application as a environment that I could then add libraries to?

Is there an easier way to add the libraries? I have tried to use pip install, but I don't understand it much, and I have been unable to find a way to pip install into my pymol environment.

Sorry, if this question has a very simple answer, I am new to programming.

Comment: maybe try to make a virtual environment first, in which you can install all your libs seperately

Comment: Forums seem to indicate that a version of Python is packaged within PyMOL.. Is there a `syspython` version of PyMOL? It says that would use the system Python version, and therefore system Python packages.

Comment: I managed to add pymol to anaconda as a library, but I am unable to launch it as a program from there. If I could figure out how to do so, it would also solve the problem.

Comment: In PyMol you could try `import sys` and then `print(sys.executable)` which should give you the Python executable it is using. Inside this folder there should be a folder `scripts` and there you should find `pip` for installing programs for your PyMol instance.

Answer (score 3):

- PyMol installer installs its own Python3.
- To install PyMOL with your system anaconda you use `conda install -c schrodinger pymol`.
- To install without Anaconda [you have to compile it](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Linux_Install) after installing `python3-dev libglm-dev freeglut3-dev libglew-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev build-essential libxml++3.6-dev`, so is notoriously hard.
- Making a symbolic link from your system/conda python (say on a Mac `ln -s /Applications/PyMOL.app/Contents/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymol /Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymol`) for `pymol` and for the egg file and the Schrödinger-made dependencies `apbs` `freemol` `glew` `mengine` `mpeg_encode` `mtz2ccp4_px` `pdb2pqr` `pmw` and pip the non-Schrödinger `libopenblas` or similar hacks do not seem to work for anyone —many have tried.

So if you want to use your script in PyMOL and install a library simply call the python within PyMOL, say `/Applications/PyMOL.app/Contents/bin/python3.7` on a Mac. On a Linux you probably installed with `conda install -c schrodinger pymol` to not end up with 1.8 anyway, so this does not apply. On Windows, you will have to find where it is installed (`import sys` and `print sys.executable` in PyMOL).

So if you want to use PyMOL within your Python code `conda install -c schrodinger pymol` or compile it if pip. Yes, it's wasteful and you have to re-add the licence.
About this mode, remember to run without the display `pymol_argv = ['pymol', '-qc']` or `__main__.pymol_argv = ['pymol', '-qc']`.

Comment: A meta-footnote, this question is more suited at [bioinformatics.stackexchange.com](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to use pymol as an import in your backend code:

You could create a virtual environment based on the `python3` version that PyMOL ships. As Matteo says, it's a separate `python3` that gets installed on your system.

---

1. The way to find which one is "PyMol python"(as opposed to your other pythons) is to open PyMOL the GUI and execute `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. Props to Maximilian Peters.
2. Now that you know where the pymol's python3 exec is you can create a `virtualenv` based on it:
   `virtualenv --python="/usr/bin/python3"`.
   In my case it happened to be `/usr/bin/python` but yours might be different.
3. Now you can install packages into this virtual environment and `import pymol` to invoke its functionality alongside your regular python/django/flask/numpy code or whatever.
4. If you want to use it as a module, follow https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Linux_Install and add the `$PYMOL_PATH/modules/` folder to your python path (`export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PYMOL_PATH/modules/:"`).  So you can put your pymol in a completely different location so logn as the python that runs your main scritp/application has the `modules` files on path.

Paraphrasing Leandro [from the forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/mailman/message/35988916/):

```bash
python3 setup.py build install --home=path_to_pymol/
--install-lib=path_to_pymol/modules/ --install-scripts=path_to_pymol/
```

```
 The part you are interested in is the modules.

 In addition, you need to add `path_to_pymol/modules/` to your python
```

paths. You can add these to the `.bashrc` file:

```bash
export PYMOL_PATH=path_to_pymol/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PYMOL_PATH/modules:
```